# Using MySQL window function to section timeseries when value changes

Tags: mysql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for a way to split a dataset into sections whenever a value change inside a partition. Note that each switch of value is a new section - also if the value switches back to the same as in an earlier section.

Trying to illustrate using some dummy data:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  group_id INT,
  date DATE,
  value VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (group_id, date, value) VALUES
    (2, '2022-03-12', 'D'),
    (2, '2022-03-15', 'C'),
    (1, '2022-03-27', 'B'),
    (1, '2022-02-01', 'A'),
    (2, '2022-03-10', 'D'),
    (1, '2022-05-01', 'C'),
    (2, '2022-01-19', 'C'),
    (1, '2022-01-18', 'A'),
    (2, '2022-04-12', 'D'),
    (1, '2022-04-08', 'A');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    id,
    group_id,
    date,
    value,
    '' as section # This is the one that I don't know how to calculate
FROM test ORDER BY group_id, date;
```

Results I want (the section is not calculated correctly):

| id | group_id | date | value | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-01-18 | A | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-02-01 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-03-27 | B | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 2022-04-08 | A | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-05-01 | C | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 2022-01-19 | C | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-03-10 | D | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-03-12 | D | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-03-15 | C | 7 |
| 9 | 2 | 2022-04-12 | D | 8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gVBW4ko6SxMWwA5wYkuKY/1)

Notice that my main problem is that I cannot partition by `(group_id, value)` since it's a new section whenever the value changes, regardless if it changes *back* to an earlier value (see value `A` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a number that distinguishes which time a value has occurred for a group_id by subtracting the number of times that value has occurred for the group_id so far from the total occurrences of that group_id so far; a little thought will show you this value will always be the same within a series of the same value and always different from that same value appearing at a different time.

From that number, you can calculate your sequential section number.  There may be a way to do that directly (with one fewer subquery), but I had to use an intermediate step of getting the date that a particular run of values for a group_id started.

```
SELECT id, group_id, date, value,
    dense_rank() over (partition by group_id order by group_value_incidence_start) section
FROM (    
    SELECT id, group_id, date, value,
        min(date) over (partition by group_id, value, group_value_incidence) group_value_incidence_start
    FROM (
        SELECT id, group_id, date, value,
            count(1) over (partition by group_id order by date) -
                count(1) over (partition by group_id, value order by date) group_value_incidence
        FROM test
    ) group_value_indidences
) group_value_incidence_starts
ORDER BY group_id, section
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=135b8bf738e644a621c48fe09960e9ef)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of "Gaps and Islands" @ysth.

A solution without subselects could be something like the below where the sections are indeed unique (see your comment for details) but they are not concecutive:
https://towardsdatascience.com/gaps-and-islands-with-mysql-b407040d133d

Comment: yes, if you are wanting to group by the runs of values, as in that post, you don't need an additional subquery